# Как импортировать модуль в питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x, модули

Вообщем создала текстовой файл **text.py** и написала там **print("text")**
Потом создала новый текстовой файл **code.py** и написала там **import text.py**
И в итоге в командной строке выполнилась команда, но при этом и выдало ошибку:
[image: ошибка]

Comment: . `import text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Расширение при импорте указывать не нужно  `import text`